# Sum and ratio of convergent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

A sequence of real numbers $($$x_n$$)$ converges to $x$. Consider the following claims:

(i) The sequence $(x_{n+1}/x_n)$ converges to $1$.

(ii) The sequence $(x_{n+1} + x_n)$ converges to $2x$.

Here's what I think: 
(i) Can be shown to be false by taking the example of the sequence $2^{-n}$, as $\frac{2^{-(n+1)}}{2^{-n}}$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Now, since $x_{n+1}$ does not necessarily converge to $x$, $(x_{n+1} + x_n)$ also does not necessarily converge to $2x$. I am not sure what the mistake with my logic is. According to my teacher, (ii) is true.

Comment: How $x_{n+1}$ may not converge to $x$? Give a counterexample.

Comment: I was thinking, $2^{-(n+1)}$ can be written as $\frac{2^{-n}}{2}$. Since the terms of the sequence are halved, its limit may not be $x$.

Comment: In this case both limits are 0, halved or not.

Comment: Could your limit $x$ be infinite ?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

For $ii$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ given.
there exists an integer $N$ such that
$$n> N \;\;\implies \;\;  |x_n-x|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
but 
$$n>N \implies n+1>N$$
and

$$|x_{n+1}+x_n-2x|=$$
$$|(x_{n+1}-x)+(x_n-x)|\le$$
$$|x_{n+1}-x|+|x_n-x|<\epsilon.$$

Thus
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(x_{n+1}+x_n)=2x$$

i